# Tratar queda de link com banco Hibernate JPA timeout

Tags: hibernate, timeout

Preciso tratar queda de link da aplicação com o banco além de manter um timeOut baixo, visto que o padrão nos meus testes é de 15 segundos.

> Falha: Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException:
>   Error calling Driver#connect

Já tentei a propriedade

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.timeout" value="1"/>
```

mas não obtive sucesso.

> INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=****, password=****,
>   timeout=1}

Qual a propriedade correta ou como contornar este problema?